# Searching across multiple indexes and referenced documents in elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Considering the following structure in MongoDB -

Personnel Collection:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    GivenName: John,
    FamilyName: Smith
}
```

Appointments Collection:

```
{
    _id:105,
    Appointment Type: Puncture Repair
    PersonnelID: 1
    AppointmentDatetime: ...
}
```

Both of these are indexed in elasticsearch, currently just in a personnel and appointments index respectively.

What I'd like to acheive is to be able to query elasticsearch with

"John smith puncture repair"

and have it find the appointment record.

Is it possible to acheive this, and how would be the best way to go about it? can I create some kind of combined index based on the reference provided by the PersonnelID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Elasticsearch 2.x documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html) states:

> both the parent and the child use the same routing value—the _id of the parent—and so they are both stored on the same shard

Since a shard can only belong to a single index both parent and child end up in the same index. Which means that you can't have separate personel and appointments indices and instead they should be different document types inside the same index.

Answer (score 1):

You could use parent-child mapping in elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html